# Difference between options and mandatory arguments with pgfkeys

Tags: pgfkeys

I try to use the pgfkeys package. Hereafter there is a short example of a simple command which use pgfkeys. I would like to know why the containts of a variable is not considered in a same way in the case of it is a mandatory argument of the command and in the case it is a option.

As you can see below, if I use `#2` or `\prop` I do not obtain the same output.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\pgfkeys{
    /nom/.code=\def\nom{#1},
    /prenom/.code=\def\prenom{#1},
    /prop/.code=\def\prop{#1},
    /prop/.default = {age,ville,couleur}
}

\newcommand{\qui}[2][]{
    \pgfkeys{#1}
    I am \prenom{} \nom{} !

    \medskip

    \#2 contains : #2

    \medskip

    prop contains : \prop

    \medskip

    If I use \#2 I get :\\
    \foreach \item in {#2} {
        \item \\
    }

    \medskip

    If I use prop option I get :\\
    \foreach \item in {\prop} {
        \item \\
    }
}

\begin{document}
\qui[prenom = toto, nom = titi, prop = {29,perpignan,bleu}]{29,perpignan,bleu}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to use `\foreach` to cycle over a comma separated list that's stored in a macro, you'll need to use `\foreach \item in \prop` (without the `{...}`). If it's stored in a macro argument (like `#2`), you do need the `{...}`. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes it was that. But strangely I thought I had already tested this ...

Comment: You can use `/nom/.store in = \nom`, etc, to just save a value in a macro.  This is a little less writing.

Answer (score 1):

You see similar things with most loop macros. If you go

```
  \foreach \item in {a,b,c}
```

then the loop will spin three times with `\item` being set to `a` on the first time.

If you go

```
\def\prop{a,b,c}
\foreach \item in {\prop}
```

The loop will just spin once, with `\item` being defined to be `\prop` and only later expanding to `a,b,c` when the item is used.

Comment: ...and if you use `\foreach \item in \prop`, the loop will spin three times again...

Comment: Yes saw that in your top comment after I posted, you have the advantage of having used pgfkeys I suspect:-)